# CPU Profiler Android Studio

Tags: performance, android-studio, cpu-usage

I am facing a problem with my Android App.

My application get a microphone by using Native Code in C and other services like MQTT.
But actually my app use a lot of CPU usage and a notification request the user to set my app on a deep sleep mode.

So I'm searching what part of my code use as much CPU and when I start CPU Profiler I see some Thread that use a lot of CPU but I don't know what part of my code it is.

[image]

My question is : How to know what Thread indicate in the CPU Profiler, corresponds to which service or thread of my code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem basically by setting a name to my thread like that :

```
thread.setName("MainActivity_Thread");
```

This allow to display the name of the thread to the CPU Profiler.